# What to do to make the clock in the microwave always correct?

Tags: clock, rtc, microwave

My new microwave has the same problem, after setting the correct time, after a week there is already 40 minutes forward.
I even thought to install my RTC in it, but the manufacturer should somehow manage it by himself to make the hour work properly.
I don't understand why every one of my microwaves, including my friends, always has the same problem.

Comment: Crystals drift.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 40 minutes in a week is 1 part in 250! That’s not crystal drift. That’s a defective unit or a really bad design.

Comment: Unlikely to be a crystal in there - probably the cheapest ceramic resonator or R-C oscillator they could find.

Comment: Without knowing the exact model of microwave and having a schematic, the best answer is probably to just not bother using the microwave clock - buy an actual clock - something whose primary function is keeping time not heating food.

Comment: @modinfo: Some clocks are synchronised with mains frequency - 50 Hz in your Germany. Are you running on mains or on a generator or inverter supply?

Comment: @Transistor Of course, on the mains supply, with 50 Hz.

Comment: Do you actually need the clock at all? (My microwave does not show anything if the time is not set.)

Comment: @CL: It is nice to have, I look quite often at the clock in a microwave.

Answer (score 4):

Microwave oven clocks are almost universally based on counting power line cycles. There must be something in your area that is producing enough noise on the power line that causes the clock to count extra cycles. You could either track down what that is and eliminate it, or try plugging the microwave into a power line filter to see whether it helps.

Comment: The chances of this being the problem is the fact that it also seem to happen to his friend's devices, presumably all living in the same area.